# Cypher - given relationship, get the nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I do the query

```
MATCH (:Label1 {prop1: "start node"}) -[relationships*1..10]-> ()
UNWIND relationships as relationship
RETURN DISTINCT relationship
```

How do I get nodes for each of acquired relationship to get result in format:

```
╒════════╤════════╤═══════╕
│"from"  │"type"  │"to"   │
╞════════╪════════╪═══════╡
├────────┼────────┼───────┤
└────────┴────────┴───────┘
```

Is there a function such as `type(r)` but for getting nodes from relationship?

Comment: Why not `MATCH (a)-[relationships*1..10]->(b) RETURN a, b`?

Comment: Because in `MATCH (a)-[relationships*1..10]->(b) RETURN a, b` result `a` is always a starting node, and `relationships` is a `List` of relationships from `a` to `b`. In short, result missing the intermediate nodes. So problem of gaining distinct list of relationships with their left and right nodes still persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, such functions do exist!

- `startNode(r)` to get the start node from relationship `r`
- `endNode(r)` to get the end node

Here's the final query:

```
MATCH () -[relationships*1..10]-> ()
UNWIND relationships as r
RETURN startNode(r) as from, type(r) as type, endNode(r) as to
```

Comment: Just curious, can we simply do `MATCH (src)-[r]-(dst) RETURN src AS from, type(r) AS type, dst AS to` to get what you want?

Comment: The key part is a variable depth of the query, without `*1..10` your query works completely the same as mine. But with variable depth there are problems I explained in comment on the question.

Answer (score 2):

RomanMitasov and ray have working answers above.

I don't think they quite get at what you want to do though, because you're basically returning every relationship in the graph in a sort of inefficient way. I say that because without a start or end position, specifying a path length of 1-10 doesn't do anything.

For example:

`CREATE (r1:Temp)-[:TEMP_REL]->(r2:Temp)-[:TEMP_REL]->(r3:Temp)`

Now we have a graph with 3 Temp nodes with 2 relationships: from r1 to r2, from r2 to r3.

Run your query on these nodes:

```
MATCH (:Temp)-[rels*1..10]->(:Temp)
UNWIND rels as rel
RETURN startNode(rel), type(rel), endNode(rel)
```

And you'll see you get four rows. Which is not what you want because there are only two distinct relationships.

You could modify that to return only distinct values, but you're still over-searching the graph.

To get an idea of what relationships are in the graph and what they connect, I use a query like:

```
MMATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
RETURN labels(n), type(r), labels(m), count(r)
```

The downside of that, of course, is that it can take a while to run if you have a very large graph.

If you just want to see the structure of your graph:
`CALL db.schema.visualization()`

Best wishes and happy graphing! :)

Comment: Sry for misunderstanding, actually my real query includes boundaries and `distinct` operations. I just omitted everything except the very problem because it was really hard to find these two functions (neo4j forums and docs are such a mess).

I'll add a disclaimer to the question.

Btw thanks for suggestions, and thanks for pointing out the duplicates issue!

Comment: In that case, your own answer below works fine. :)